# How can one disable power aperture for video shooting with the Nikon D750?

Tags: video-recording, nikon

I'm using a lens with an aperture ring that allows changing the aperture in a smooth, continuous manner.

- I've set up the D750 to allow me to use the aperture ring on the lens to change the aperture instead of the normal dial.
- When I use LiveView in photo mode, I can change the aperture from the lens as expected, and looking through the lens as I rotate the aperture ring shows a smooth transition
- When switching to LiveView video mode (and starting to record) however, power aperture kicks in and constantly tries to adjust the aperture to a "round" value, both making noise and cancelling the whole advantage offered by the lens.

Is there any way to disable this? Changing the `Multi-selector power aperture` setting has no effect.

The lens has a CPU chip and the firmware version of the camera is 1.02.